# Determining File Location for List Library

Tags: list, document-library, sharepoint-foundation, infrastructure

I have inherited a SharePoint system with no documentation on the infrastructure.  I have determined so far that this system is MOSS2007 Foundation, that the IIS site sits on one server while the SQL database sits on another, but not much more.

There are files in a "document library" that clients and employees can both post files to.  I do not know where these actual files reside within our network once they are uploaded to the Portal.  How do I determine this?

Additionally, is there a tool I can use to give me all the information regarding my SharePoint infrastructure, or a reference where I can learn to find these components on the existing setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files uploaded to a SharePoint document library normally reside in the SQL database itself, unless there is a mechanism in place to store them outside SQL (specifically, a "Remote Blob Storage" provider). SharePoint splits its databases by type of use. For a web site, the database is normally named "WSS_Content_" but the previous administrator could have named it differently.

On the server with the IIS site you should have Central Administration in the start menu. You can access it with the farm administrator account, and in there you will find a list of all web applications, and for each a list of web site collections. Your document library can be on any of them. If you want to find specifically which database, you will first need to locate the parent web site and parent web application, then in Central Admin you can see which Content Database is used by which web app. Your best bet is to find out which URL the clients access and work your way up from there.

Central Administration will provide you with a lot of information about your farm.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the "Farm Administrator Account?" If not, can I use my DA account?

Comment: DA account? Open your Computer Management console on the SharePoint server, you should have groups named WSS_<something> (WSS_ADMIN, WSS_WPG, WSS_RESTRICTED_WPG_V4). The members of those groups are either the installation accounts, admin accounts or both. See also http://sharepointpolice.com/blog/2010/05/04/finding-the-setup-user-administrator-account-of-a-sharepoint-farm/